# Is there anything to make answer as disable after some downvote?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes

I was searching for answer and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443989/why-set-variables-inside-the-construct-of-a-php-class-when-you-can-set-them-when) post and found that last answer with 3 downvotes looks disable.

is there any limit define for it? i have not seen this before. see below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer element in the dom has the class `downvoted-answer`. I don't know exactly what the downvote limit is in order to get this class, but you can try to check if it's -3, by upvoting it (to get it to -2), refresh the page to see if it's still greyed out then retract your upvote.
If nothing changes when you refresh the page it means the limit is -2 or -1. So you can find a -2 post and try the same thing.
If something changes it means the limit is -3.

[EDIT]
I just tested myself because you made me curious and apparently the limit is -3.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will also check

Comment: Threshold is indeed -3 - that's documented somewhere on MSE, though I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 6):

Answers with a score of -3 and lower are shown grayed-out to visually highlight that they are probably not good. This does not mean that they are *disabled* in any way though.

Comment: Thanks +1 for your effort and time. i understand limit is 3 downvote